# How to Validate Dynamic form with PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have searched over SO for quite awhile so I apologize if a similar question is asked and answered but I don't believe there is.

I am using a PHP validation script and jQuery Validate to process all of the forms on my site. With known fields, no issues. However, there are pages which a user can enter additional person(s) information.

A user is asked to enter his family member's names in a form. The user can submit the form or choose to add additional family members to the form. I have not quite figured out how to properly cycle through all the fields and display unique messages based on the users input in jQuery but know I can do so with metadata and the validation plugin.

My issue lies with PHP. I can take each array and run though foreach loops, however, if an error is found in ANY field, an error is generated and the form is displayed again with all fields' previously entered data. I am unable to determine how to point each field's original data to it given the fields are built dynamically when errors appear.

The SIMPLEST METHOD I can come up with for demonstration is this:

> A user must enter the percentages of pie he wants his friends to eat.
>   He must give out 100% of his pie. The user can choose to dynamically
>   add friends to his pie eating extravaganza but each person must
>   receive atleast 1% of the pie and they must all together eat 100%.

[**Sample code**](http://jsfiddle.net/TkDtd/2/)

I have created a sample script here which shows the form setup but obviously there is no PHP backend to test. You will need to use your imagination the backend works (I have added into the comments in the html). The same principle would apply with PHP SESSION variable since this data would need to be passed from page to page (if a user revisits this page, the amounts entered for each piece of pie should display). Also, I think it goes without saying but this data **MUST BE** validated server-side.

Comment: So, you will have an array of input data, some of it invalid, and you need to build a form that is prepopulated with it? You just loop over it and build a form element for each one. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @Okonomiyaki3000 - The form is already built then dynamic fields are added. Are you suggesting once the page is reloaded (and therefore validated), in the presence of an error to ignore the existing form code and simply build a new form with the fields I have already collected?

Comment: Yes. (this comment must be at least 15 characters long)

Comment: @Okonomiyaki3000 - your answer seems to assume there is one field in the set of data collected. If each set was say, 3 fields (recipient name, % of pie received, date of birth) - this would seemingly change the way the form was rebuilt greatly, in many ways making it either 1) impossible, or 2) very, very sloppy.

Comment: Normally, you build this form dynamically with Javascript, right? Does Javascript build a sloppy form? I'm sure it does not. A form can be sloppy or neat whether it is pre-build or dynamically built. Why can't you pre-build a form exactly like the dynamic one?

Comment: @Okonomiyaki3000 - what I am saying is, in order to do this, I'm infusing a ton of logic code mixed directly with viewer HTML. Essentially I'm saying - "if form was submitted and there are errors, create a list of form fields in the format already defined below; else go ahead and display a single set of fields then allow the user to add/remove as needed". Perhaps you are correct as the only way but I think there may be a cleaner more appropriate way to do this.

Comment: there's no need to mix your logic and display code. You can surely find a way to separate these. But I wouldn't say this method is the only way either. If you're more comfortable with making changes to the front end code, maybe you could create a json object with all default values, write that to the page and write a javascript function to read it and build the form dynamically on load.

Answer (score 0):

Will you not be reloading the page in the event of a PHP error? In which case you know the index of the error in the foreach loop, saved off to some variable - most likely an array to handle multiple errors. When you print the options back out and you are looping through the submitted array again can you not add an additional css class to the text box when you reach a count that is in your error array.

Comment: Did you view the sample code? The page is reloading, the form action is set to reload itself but the indexes are named arrays. What is to determine which section of the dynamic array is shown and better yet, how many dynamic fields were generated prior.